# NavigationView Ocupa demaciado espacio Toolbar

Tags: java, android

Estimados actualmente hago uso de NavigationView

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="#000000" />
```

en todas mis vistas implemento mi toolbar

```
<include layout="@layout/actionbar_toolbar"/>
```

Codigo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subTitle"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_below="@id/title"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImagensiguienteToolbar"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:onClick="goToAdd"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImagenatrasToolbar"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:onClick="goToBack" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

el tema es que al ponerle una flecha de lado de la izquierda me queda asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y la verdad que ese espacio en blanco esta como tomado por el NavigationView , ya que desde la vista del toolbar no me deja colocarlo mas a la izquierda aqui foto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aunque el visor me lo muestre pegado la limite , cuando se lo observa en un telefono queda como la primer imagen muy a la derecha , cualquier ayuda sera bienvenida

lo que no logro encontrar es donde esta este tama;o localizado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como opción puedes agregar un style a tu `Toolbar` con la propiedad [contentInsetStartWithNavigation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#setContentInsetStartWithNavigation(int)) estableciendo un valor de 0 dp :

```
<item name="contentInsetStartWithNavigation">0dp</item>
```

o programaticamente puedes definir la misma propiedad:

```
myToolbar.setContentInsetStartWithNavigation(0);
```

para eliminar el espacio entre la flecha y el botón de navegación, ya que por default tiene un valor definido.

Comment: como siempre Jorge sos el 1 , muchas gracias , siempre que investigo algo en el foro siempre siempre tus respuestas estan presentes  y siempre son correctas muchas gracias !

Comment: Me da gusto mis respuestas puedan ayudar, espero pronto tu también ayudes a otros desarrolladores, saludos!